# htaccess create all files redirect to new path

Tags: .htaccess

All my images is in this path:
root/lib/images/demo/

Now i all images move to new folder:
root/lib/images_new/demo/

How to do redirects all pictures to new address?

If user go on this address:

> root/lib/images/demo/test.png

It should be redirected in this:

> root/lib/images_new/demo/test.png

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any effort by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that the old image url http://www.example.com/root/lib/images/demo/test.png , add the following directives to a `.htaccess` in the root directory of your website

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^root/lib/images/demo/(.*)$ /root/lib/images_new/demo/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
```